# Do I need to First-Difference Before Using ARDL?

Tags: econometrics, ardl

I have a four variables, two of which are $I(0)$ and the other two are $I(1)$. 
I've decided to use ARDL (Auto regressive distributed lag) model because I have a mix of $I(0)$ and $I(1)$ variables.

Do I still need to take the first difference of all variables so that they all become $I(0)$? Or, can I run the ARDL in levels?

Comment: This [blogpost](https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2013/06/ardl-models-part-ii-bounds-tests.html) might be informative.